# Swiper Loop issues on end IE 11

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have a slider and it's set to loop

```
$ ->
mySwiper2 = new Swiper(".cultural-swiper-container",
  keyboardControl: true
  grabCursor: true
  pagination: ".cultural-swiper-container .pagination"
  paginationClickable: true
  loop: true
  autoplay: 10000
  autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
)
$(".cultural-slider .prev").on "click", (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  mySwiper2.swipePrev()

$(".cultural-slider .next").on "click", (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  mySwiper2.swipeNext()
```

The problem is that when the loop ends and it goes back to the first slide it seems like it isn't reinitialized.  Reason I say this is because it add 2 icon fonts to the beginning of the text then once I click on the slide to start the touch event or click forward and then go back it's fixed, like it reinitializes it.

```
.swiper-wrapper
    .swiper-slide.pink-slide
      .swiper-bg
        .sb-logo
          i.icon-sb-mark
        .container
          .large-5.columns.small-centered
            p We bring ideas to life, we help others realize their dreams and their goals, and we help push innovative companies to heights they aren’t able to reach on their own.
```

This is the code in IE that it does

```
.swiper-wrapper
    .swiper-slide.pink-slide
      .swiper-bg
        .sb-logo
          i.icon-sb-mark
        .container
          .large-5.columns.small-centered
            p 
              i.icon-sb-mark 
                i.icon-sb-mark 
                  We bring ideas to life, we help others realize their dreams and their goals, and we help push innovative companies to heights they aren’t able to reach on their own.
```

Not sure what is going on, it's only IE 11